# no method domReady error in console even though domReady gets called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Javascript so forgive me if I kill this question.

I've got a script to grab my latest twitter posts and place it on my blog:

http://www.joshkerr.com

It isn't working.  The error I see in the console is "no method domReady."  Yet another script I wrote runs just fine and if I step through my function, works fine.

Here is the strange part.  If I include jquery further up in my file, I get the Twitter object working, but my search http://www.joshkerr.com/search/ stops working.  So I suspect some kind of namespace issue going on.

How do I get my Twitter object to work again?

Since It is all client code, you can view source and see for yourself.

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question. `:)`

Comment: You really have to give us more to go on here.  I've been to your link and don't see the error you're talking about.  For us to help, we need to be able to see the relevant code or the actual page with the error in it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jeesh.min.js may be clobbering jQuery's $ object. Your search page throws the error "Object function h(a,b){return g(a,b)} has no method 'getJSON'". The jeesh.min.js file contains "function h(a,b){return g(a,b)}" and getJSON is a jQuery method, so there you go. I see your search page contains a block like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

It's usually considered good practice to wrap such code like so

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Your code here
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This ensures that $ is actually the jQuery object.